# ios insert more table cell rows after last index

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm trying to make an unlimited scroll table view(feed).
However, I can't get the tableview to insert more cells after the initial load.

My table has two types of cells. A collection view table cell and a regular image+label table cell. The collection view is shown only once and it's first.

Area that is giving me issues. It does at least call, it just doesn't add any more cells. Also, not sure how it knows which type of cell to add.

```
extension FeedViewController: UITableViewDelegate{
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let lastElement = venueData.count
        if indexPath.row == lastElement {
            // handle your logic here to get more items, add it to dataSource and reload tableview
            print(venueData.count)
            print("last")
            if(firstLoad){
                firstLoad = false
                return
            }
            let appendAmount = 10
            currentOffset = currentOffset+appendAmount

            let res = venueDataRequest(query:"Any",offset:10,amount:appendAmount)
            venueData.append(contentsOf: res )


            self.feedTableView.beginUpdates()
            self.feedTableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row: venueData.count-appendAmount, section: 0)], with: .automatic)
            self.feedTableView.endUpdates()


        }
    }
}
```

Full Class

```
import UIKit

class FeedViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var feedTableView: UITableView!


    let popularPlaces = getPopularPlaces()
    var firstLoad = true
    var currentOffset = 0
    var venueData = venueDataRequest(query:"Any",offset:0,amount:10)
//    var venueData: [FeedVenueData] = []


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        feedTableView.dataSource = self
        feedTableView.delegate = self
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

}

extension FeedViewController: UITableViewDelegate{
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let lastElement = venueData.count
        if indexPath.row == lastElement {
            // handle your logic here to get more items, add it to dataSource and reload tableview
            print(venueData.count)
            print("last")
            if(firstLoad){
                firstLoad = false
                return
            }
            let appendAmount = 10
            currentOffset = currentOffset+appendAmount

            let res = venueDataRequest(query:"Any",offset:10,amount:appendAmount)
            venueData.append(contentsOf: res )


            self.feedTableView.beginUpdates()
            self.feedTableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row: venueData.count-appendAmount, section: 0)], with: .automatic)
            self.feedTableView.endUpdates()


        }
    }
}

extension FeedViewController: UITableViewDataSource{
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1+venueData.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if(indexPath.row == 0){
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "FeedPopularPlaceCollectionViewTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! FeedPopularPlaceCollectionViewTableViewCell
            cell.setup()
            return cell
        }else{
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "FeedVenueTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! FeedVenueTableViewCell

            let pos = indexPath.row - 1
            cell.venueName.text = venueData[pos].name
            cell.venueImage.image = venueData[pos].image

            print(indexPath.row)
            return cell
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: What is the issue you have got, if statement isn't called or it's called but cell isn't inserted?

Comment: statement is called and it runs, it just doesn't insert any rows.

Comment: When you call `print(venueData.count)`, does it have different value each time?

Comment: @trungduc the first time it says 10 and then won't display from there. So data is being appended to the array

Comment: Try adding the new data in didEndDisplayingCell instead of willDisplayCell method. willDisplayCell method tells that tableview is already in the mode of editing and is not finished yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is because you add 10 items but only insert 1 cell. After first time called, `if indexPath.row == lastElement` will never reached again because `indexPath.row = 1` and `lastElement = 10`.

To fix it, instead of inserting only 1 cell, insert 10 cells after adding new items and call `insertRows` on main queue

```
var indexPaths = (venueData.count-appendAmount+1..<venueData.count+1).map { IndexPath(row: $0, section: 0) }
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.feedTableView.insertRows(at: indexPaths, with: .automatic)
}
```

Comment: What happens after you try my code? Were any cell inserted?

Comment: No, unfortunately. I tried `self.feedTableView.reloadData()` and that seems to be working, but would still like to know why it isnt working with insert

Comment: I have updated my answer, you can try it again. It should be `venueData.count-appendAmount+1`

Comment: unfortunately that's not doing anything either :/

Comment: @TrevorWood Updated my answer. Call `insertRows` in main queue resolve problem

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code to insert more rows, when user comes to last cell.

```
func scrollViewDidEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, willDecelerate decelerate: Bool) {
    //Bottom Refresh
    if scrollView == feedTableView {
        if ((scrollView.contentOffset.y + scrollView.frame.size.height) >= scrollView.contentSize.height) {
            //Insert Row in Tableview
        print(venueData.count)
        print("last")
        if(firstLoad){
            firstLoad = false
            return
        }
        let appendAmount = 10
        currentOffset = currentOffset+appendAmount

        let res = venueDataRequest(query:"Any",offset:10,amount:appendAmount)
        venueData.append(contentsOf: res )


        self.feedTableView.beginUpdates()
        self.feedTableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row: venueData.count-appendAmount, section: 0)], with: .automatic)
        self.feedTableView.endUpdates()

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

At this line

```
 self.feedTableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row: venueData.count-appendAmount, section: 0)], with: .automatic)
```

why you insert at index  `venueData.count-appendAmount`

```
self.feedTableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row: venueData.count, section: 0)], with: .automatic)
```

Comment: Take a look at `numberOfRowsInSection` method